# why can't I prune elements of nested arrays with redact - mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I want to prune the elements of a nested array which do not satisfy a certain condition:

The structure of my document is:

```
{ 
   "array1":[ 
      { 
         "array2":[ 
            { 
               "field1":{ 
                  "field2":"MATCH"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}

The redact query I´m trying to do is: 

db.getCollection("collection").aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$match" : {
                "array1.array2.field1.field2" : "MATCH"
            }
        },
        {
            "$redact" : {
                "$cond" : {
                    "if" : {
                        "$in" : [
                            "$array1.array2.field1.field2",
                            [
                                "MATCH"
                            ]
                        ]
                    },
                    "then" : "$$KEEP",
                    "else" : "$$PRUNE"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

I never can get any result. However if I replace  "$array1.array2.field1.field2" with "MATCH" I get a true condition and keeps all the documents. My question is what am I doing wrong for the value of the expression "$array1.array2.field1.field2"  never to be equal to "MATCH" if it is the value of field2?

I also need the returned documents in its original structure.